# What does this H buff icon mean?

Tags: payday-3

Today I was doing No Rest for the Wicked and noticed this H icon in my buffs area. It's not the icon for edge, grit, or rush for certain, it's some kind of fourth icon that I've never seen before. What does this buff icon mean?

[image: Payday 3 screenshot featuring the icon for edge and another icon that looks like the letter H]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This icon appears when an ECM is placed and used. It is basically a way of showing how long the ECM is still active for.